# How to give path of the music file that is inside the Java package?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I created a package named sounds in my Java project and my sound is in this package. However, I get an java.io.FileNotFoundException error with this code. So how can I give the path of this file?

```
  path="sounds/hit.wav"
```

path is given like above

```
  public class Sound {

AudioInputStream audio;
Clip clip;
//String path;

public void play(String path)
{
    try{
        File soundFile =new File(path);
        audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audio);
        clip.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I also tried this one and it gives an IOException:

```
    clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
        new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sounds/hit.wav"))));
```

Can you please tell me how can I solve this problem?

Here is my file structure:

[image]

Comment: What does AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(); method takes as an argument? String or File?

Comment: I am sorry, I edited it, It is file.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did at first place but it gives java.io.FileNotFoundException  error.

Comment: Java's not going to somehow stuff those files into your compiled bytecode. You have to get a build process to make a jar containing those files. I guess Eclipse can build a jar from a project, but I'd have Maven include that directory in the jar build with a <resource> statement, and then use @Michał Tabor's solution to load it from the jar at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
URL urlToHit = this.getClass().getResource("/edu/iyte/ceng316/resource/hit.wav");
System.out.println(urlToHot);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("sounds/hit.wav"));
```

Comment: still java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: NPE means this file doesn't exists in the given directory. The code I gave you tries to get a hit.wav file from a directory which is in the same place where the Java class is. Is it true in your case?

Comment: sound and Java class are in different packages.

Comment: Could you edit your question and post your directories structure so I could see how it all looks like?

Comment: Can you look at now,please?

Comment: Do you have some use of creating a different package for keeping your resources? If I were you I would create a directory called "resources" or "sounds" in your main package (with all game stuff) and keep your sounds there. OR eventually you could try something like this: clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("..edu.iyte.ceng316.resource/hit.wav")); . The ".." stands for a parent directory.